# Solve an equation involving factorial: $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-2)!}=990$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

> For this equation:
>
> $$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-2)!}=990$$

I need help with the working to the answer. 
Well I was stuck on the bit where I had ended up with: 
  $$(n+1)n(n-1)=990$$
  $$(n^2-1)n=990$$
  $$n^3-n=990$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-2)!} = 990$$
$$ \frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)!}{(n-2)!} = 990$$
$$(n+1)(n)(n-1) = 990$$
$$(n+1)(n)(n-1) = 99 \times 10$$
$$(n+1)(n)(n-1) = 11 \times 10 \times 9$$

thus $n=10$

Comment: +1 For solving the final polynomial equation using factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thanks i was stuck on: (n+1)n(n-1)=990 but instead i went to (n^2-1)n=990

Comment: Because the result is much more obvious. To make life still easier, you could by yourself rewrite SMath's last equation as $(n+1)(n)(n-1) = 11\times 10 \times 9$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Cancellation by division of factorial common factors in numerator and denominator should leave you with three terms, giving a cubic polynomial.